# Align two icons to one line horizontally

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two icons inside the "col" class. It is sprite icons wrapped with anchor tag. It is stacked one on above. I want it be in one line horizontally. Also I want to reorder it with the bootstrap "order" class . How can I do that? Please help me!

I tried to wrap it with additional row and col.And use flex with flex-direction but nothing helped.

Inside footer

Two icons what I want to align inside my .segment-six class

Icons above each other. I want to see it in horizontal. I want to reorder these stuff to be .segment-four be first then .segment-six then .segment-five in stack

```css
.segment-six {
  /* display: flex; 
   flex-direction: row; */
  width: 120px;
  /* margin-left:auto;
   margin-right: 20%; */
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    /* padding-left: 50px; */
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 segment-four">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 segment-six">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 segment-five">
    <p>©TOO SMART PAY ПЛАТЕЖНАЯ ОРГАНИЗАЦИЯ №02-17-012 OT 09.02.2017 РЕЕСТР НАЦИОНАЛЬНОГО БАНКА РК</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please use images from placeholder.com and fix the CSS which had // style comments and update to a [mcve]

Comment: Which Bootstrap version U r using for this?

Comment: It's a bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your css

**css**

```
.segment-six a{
    float: left;
 }
.segment-six a img{
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: This makes a vertical line of images, not a horizontal line.

Comment: so please add float:left;

Comment: Back to what it was.

Comment: Do you actually test what you write in your answer? `flaot` instead of `float`, for instance.

Comment: yse.. but  i can't see your image

Comment: I know you're trying to be helpful, and that's a good thing, but your answer, so far, has been of very poor quality. Please try to do better.

Comment: i am sorry for this... i change code .. pls check now

Comment: It still doesn't work. PS: this is not my question, in case you thought that.

Comment: @Ranjithv with float you can't easily order items to be before the other. Bootstrap has something called `order` which is perfect for this.

Comment: if you want change order means.. you should add d-flex for parent div

Answer (score 0):

Use `order` instead of `.segment` if you are using bootstrap 4.

For example: `.order-5` instead of `.segment-five`.

The items are horizontally to eachother, have you included bootstrap in your header?
 `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">`

```css
.order-6 {
  /* display: flex; 
   flex-direction: row; */
  width: 120px;
  /* margin-left:auto;
   margin-right: 20%; */
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    /* padding-left: 50px; */
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 order-4">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/888/fff.jpg&text=image+1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 order-6">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/888/fff.jpg&text=image+2"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/888/fff.jpg&text=image+3"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 order-5">
    <p>©TOO SMART PAY ПЛАТЕЖНАЯ ОРГАНИЗАЦИЯ №02-17-012 OT 09.02.2017 РЕЕСТР НАЦИОНАЛЬНОГО БАНКА РК</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Further explanation about the order class: 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#order-classes

Comment: Yes sir I added it.

Comment: Is the fiddle the way you wanted it? Or did I understand your question wrong?